# The maximum nametable character count quota (16384) has been exceeded

Tags: wcf, configuration, wcf-binding

I've just increased the number of methods in my ServiceContract. when I update the Service Reference in Visual Studio I get the message:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
> 'net.tcp://xxxxx.com:8002/DataQueryService/mex'.
>
> There is an error in the XML document.
>
> The maximum nametable character
> count quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. The
> nametable is a data structure used to store strings encountered during
> XML processing - long XML documents with non-repeating element names,
> attribute names and attribute values may trigger this quota. This
> quota may be increased by changing the MaxNameTableCharCount property
> on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML
> reader.

The original server side config was:

```
 <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="XXXXX.DataQueryService.ServiceBehavior" name="XXXXX.DataQueryService.QueryService">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://xxxxx.com:8002/DataQueryService" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint name="MexEndpoint" address="mex" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="unsecureTcpMex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
</services>

<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="unsecureTcpMex">
            <tcpTransport portSharingEnabled="True" />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>    
</bindings>
```

which I modified to:

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="unsecureTcpMex">
            <textMessageEncoding>
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            </textMessageEncoding>
            <tcpTransport portSharingEnabled="True" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"  />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>    
</bindings>
```

What other changes do I need to make to my config to get this working?

**Update**
Following @Chris's advice I tried updating the config file for SVCUtil. I added a name to my endpoint so that it would match (updated above). The SvcUtil.config is now as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="unsecureTcpMex">
                    <textMessageEncoding>
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="unsecureTcpMex"
                contract="IMetadataExchange"
                name="MexEndpoint" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe your messages are just too big or composed of too many xml elements/attributes?

Comment: It's the number of operation contracts that has increased. This is causing the problem.

Comment: What version of WCF are you working with (both sides)?

Answer (score 3):

```
<binding name="NameSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true" messageEncoding="Text">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="1638400" />
    <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
</binding>
```

Take a look to this line: **maxNameTableCharCount="1638400"**

Comment: Thanks Bart, but I have already increase that value from its default of 16384 to the max value for an integer - 2147483647.

Answer (score 1):

I don't suppose its practical to split up the operations into multiple contracts? Mind if I ask how many service operations we're talking about?

Have you tried the solutions in this post? 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17592561-c470-452a-a52c-2a5a2839582c/metadataexchangeclient-and-nametable-character-count-quota

Among other suggestions are using the Discovery protocol to read metadata, which does not have any reader quotas:
http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.discovery.discoveryclientprotocol.aspx

The solution at the bottom suggests you change the default reader quotas in code before starting the service. I believe this would have to be done in a custom ServiceHost factory. Please let me know if you would assistance with that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I had already looked at the first link you gave. Our solution is probably already too mature to change the discovery method as suggested. I have seen that other people have had success changing the readerQuotas so I'd like to do the same. It means it's just a couple of lines change to the config files. When you say "in a custom ServiceHost factory", what do you mean by this? Is it not possible to do in the config files?

Comment: This page describes how you can create a custom service host to do some custom configuration of your service, in addition to reading the config files, including how to use with IIS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx   This will allow you to set reader quotas before the service is created, which I believe is the source of your problem, and why it can't be done in config files alone. Good luck!

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that SvcUtil.exe and Visual Studios Service references will still not work with this solution. Our build process is automated and it's actually the build that is failing as well so I need to find a solution where I can just modify the config file. A number of other people have managed to successfully overcome this problem by modifying the client-side config file. I'm just trying to find out what errors I have in my config file.

Comment: I would like to point out that there is some code at the bottom of the page on the first link that fixed this for me. I'm using IIS6 and had to use reflection to increase the MaxNameTableCharCount in the ReaderQuotas in System.ServiceModel. I couldn't fix inside the config, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:
http://geekswithblogs.net/claraoscura/archive/2007/08/20/114806.aspx
appears that the solution is to create a config file for svcutil and place it in the same folder as it.

Comment: thanks for that. I added a config file for SvcUtil.exe which I have detailed above. However I am still getting the same error. Was it just the SvcUtil file I need to change or was it the Server side one as well?

Comment: You should only change the consuming application

Comment: OK, I tried modifying the config file for SvcUtil (as above) but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the new value for the MaxNameTableCharCount property programmatically:

```
Binding binding = endpoint.Binding;

XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas myReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
myReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = something;
myReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = something;
myReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = something;
myReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = something;
myReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = something;

binding.GetType().GetProperty("ReaderQuotas").SetValue(binding, myReaderQuotas, null);
```

Note:  you have to set it BEFORE the client proxy and/or service host are created. Once created, they can't be changed.

Comment: Our build process is automated and it's actually the build that is failing as well so I need to find a solution where I can just modify the config file. A number of other people have managed to successfully overcome this problem by modifying the client-side config file. I'm just trying to find out what errors I have in my config file.

Comment: Does your error message still says: "The maximum nametable character count quota (16384)". I said to try this because it doesn't look like itøs reading your new value for that (16384 instead of your 2147483647).  Once I had a similar problem but changing it from the config file would not work, but it worked at runtime.

Comment: Yes the error message is still the same. The way our build script was set up I need to specify the value in the config file. It's worked for other users by changing the config. Is there any reason why it's not working for me?